# How to access On-premise TFS from untrusted domain when NTLM is disabled

Tags: authentication, tfs, kerberos

Our organisation is disabling NTLM due to concerns with its pass the hash weakness.  Our team includes 3rd party developers who use PCs that are in an untrusted domain.  When they attempt to access our on-premise TFS instance from Visual Studio the authentication fails.  My research shows that this is due to Kerberos only working when a trust exists.

Does anyone know of a work-around?  The security team are simply suggesting we set up a VDI environment!

Answer (score 0):

Set up a VPN connection. This will allow you to create a tunnel between networks so that those machines in outside domain can hit your server. Another way is  exposing TFS to the outside world by allowing the appropriate ports through your firewall. Which may runs counter to the security requirements for your organisation.